# Spring Data Cassandra getQueriedHost

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring Data Casandra (2.0.14.RELEASE) and my repository extends `CassandraRepository<T, MapId>`. I want to get the [queried host](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getQueriedHost--). Is there a way to get the `execution info` when we call the CRUD methods on Repository ?

I want to know which HOST was queried during every CRUD operation. Is it possible to write something in background thread & log it, which **triggers a call to `getQueriedHost` whenever any CRUD operation happens on the Repository** ?

Thanks in advance

Angshuman

Answer (score -1):

The spring cassandra connecter uses the Datastax Java client under the hood, you can see how to construct the [client connection here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.getting-started).

The result-set that contains the result contains a list of the various hosts queried:

```
Cluster.Builder b = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1");
Cluster cluster = b.build();
Session session = cluster.connect();

SimpleStatement ss = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables LIMIT 1");
ss.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);

ResultSet rs = session.execute(ss);
for (Row r : rs.all()) {
    System.out.println("res: " + r);
}

// you can get the contacted hosts here, this will show you what node 
// coordinated the request from the Cassandra side. 
for (ExecutionInfo ei : rs.getAllExecutionInfo()) {
    System.out.println("Host queried: " + ei.getQueriedHost().getAddress());
}
```

Example output:

```
res: Row[...]
Host queried: /127.0.0.1
Host queried: /127.0.0.2
Host queried: /127.0.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I do not do any of these. Everything is abstracted out by the Repository. I just call Repository methods from PoJo. I do not explicitly prepare statements and explicity call execute (what you did `session.execute`). Repository does not expose this `ResultSet` object. It has `findAll`, `findAllById`, etc.... methods.